# mysql select top unique values with inner join

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join

I have 2 tables that look like this:

```
users (uid, name)
-------------------
|  1  |  User 1   |
|  2  |  User 2   |
|  3  |  User 3   |
|  4  |  User 4   |
|  5  |  User 5   |
-------------------

highscores (user_id, time)
-------------------
|  3 |   12005    |
|  3 |   29505    |
|  3 |   17505    |
|  5 |   19505    |
-------------------
```

I want to query only for users that have a highscore and only the top highscore of each user. The result should look like:

```
------------------------
|  User 3 |   29505    |
|  User 5 |   19505    |
------------------------
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT user.name, highscores.time
FROM user
INNER JOIN highscores ON user.uid = highscores.user_id
ORDER BY time ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 10
```

Actually this returns multiple highscores of the same user. I also tried to group them but it did not work since it did not return the best result but a random one (eg: for user id 3 it returned 17505 instead of 29505).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the aggregated function `MAX()` together with `group by` clause.

```
SELECT  a.name, MAX(b.`time`) maxTime
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN highscores b
            on a.uid = b.user_id
GROUP BY a.name
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1459f/1)

Answer (score 1):

Your effort of grouping users was correct. You just needed to use `MAX(time)` aggregate function instead of selecting only `time`.

I think you wrote older query was like this:

```
SELECT name, time 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN highscores ON users.uid = highscores.user_id 
GROUP BY name,time
```

But actual query should be:

```
SELECT user.name, MAX(`time`) AS topScore
FROM users 
INNER JOIN highscores ON users.uid = highscores.user_id
GROUP BY user.name
```